# Get AVG from all records grouped by condition and then get AVG of these averages

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I have following table:

```
+--------+-------+
|Username|Points |
+--------+-------+
|User1   | 75.00 |
|User1   | 87.50 |
|User1   |100.00 |
|User1   | 40.00 |
|User1   | 50.00 |
|User2   |100.00 |
|User3   | 37.50 |
|User3   | 12.50 |
+--------+-------+
```

I want the query to show only 1 Field with User1 with the average of the 5 fields where username = User1 and the same with User3. Then get the average of all users.

So it would be:

```
AVG (avg user1 + avg user2 + avg user3)
```

Any Ideas how to accomplish that?

I have tried the following but gives me the wrong avg:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(finalgrade),2) AS grade FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT(u.username), gg.finalgrade AS finalgrade FROM ...
```

lots of JOINs and WHEREs

```
)
AS average
```

Comment: Do you want the average user average, or the average of all the records? Your title and question seem to disagree. The first would weigh the User averages equally, the second would weigh each record equally (with more emphasis on User1's results).

Comment: I know there's an sql statement that returns you both totals and sub totals of a column, and I think it works with average, does anyone know this statement ?

Comment: @ValentinO. I think you mean [WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html). Again you'd have to consider the answer to my previous comment, I think it would average all records, rather than average the averages.. but I could be wrong.

Comment: Judging from @PSalmon's answer WITH ROLLUP averages all records.. which might not be what OP requires.

Comment: Going by the accepted answer, I have updated the question title.. it appears OP wanted the average of the averages.

Comment: so many answers, so fast 0.o

Comment: I needed the avg of the different users if they have done more than one quiz so with this values I can get the complete avg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a subquery. First get the average based on the user and then average those, just like you said:

```
SELECT AVG(points) from (
  SELECT AVG(points) AS points FROM ... GROUP BY username) a;
```

There's no need for DISTINCT.

Comment: Why run a subquery when the above query can be simplified as select avg(points) from <table>?

Comment: @TheShooter It cannot. What is the average of 2, 2, 4? What is the average of avg(2, 2), 4? Completely different things.

Comment: Thanks, thats what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query.

```
 SELECT Username, ROUND(AVG(Points),2) AS Points 
        FROM YourTable
          JOIN...
        GROUP BY username
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
SELECT 
     * 
FROM
(
    (
         SELECT
              UserName
              ,AVG(Points) AS AvgUserPoints
         FROM <table>
         GROUP BY UserName
    ) AS T1
    INNER JOIN 
    (
         SELECT
             AVG(Points) AvgPoints 
         FROM <table>
    ) AS T2 ON 1=1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the table is:
create table user_points
(username varchar(10), points number(5,2));

The following query gives the results in rows:

```
select username, avg(points) from user_points where username in ('User1','User3') group by username
union all
select 'All', avg(points) from user_points;
```

To get the same result in columns you need a table with a single row and column, and implement the AVGs in 3 separate subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

```
select username,avg(points) averg,count(*) obs
from t
group by username with rollup
```

result

```
+----------+------------+-----+
| username | averg      | obs |
+----------+------------+-----+
| User1    |  70.500000 |   5 |
| User2    | 100.000000 |   1 |
| User3    |  25.000000 |   2 |
| NULL     |  62.812500 |   8 |
+----------+------------+-----+
```

Comment: Beware, OP might want the User averages averaged with equal weighting.. which is 65.17, not 62.81. See my comments on the question.